# Header is dissolved within the page

Tags: tables, sectioning, header-footer, page-breaking

[image]

Hello Everyone, I am having a tough time fixing this. As you can see that the reference columns are hiding behind the page. Is it wrong with my package? Could someone please give a suggestion?

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[compsoc,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{xxx\\

}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} xxx} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department of yyy} \\
\textit{zzz}\\
\\
}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
component, formatting, style, styling, insert
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Background}









\section{Study Design}
 
\subsection{ Research Question}
In this section, stemming from the above background reasoning for the research problems, we formulate the following research questions? \\
RQ1 : What are the xxx?\\
RQ2 : What are the xxx?




\subsection{Method}
\subsubsection{SLR}


\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{5cm}|}
\hline   
    & i1: xxx  \\
    & i2: xxx   \\
xxx     & i3: xxx   \\
    & i4: xxx   \\
    & i5: xxx  \\
    
\hline
    & R1: xxx  \\
   & R2: xxx   \\
   & R3: xxx   \\
xxx    & R4: xxx   \\
   & R5: xxx   \\
   & R6: xxx   \\
   & R7: xxx   \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1.png}
    \caption{ }
    \label{Fig: xxx}
\end{figure}    


\subsubsection{Grey Literature}



\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2.png}
    \caption{grey literature type}
    \label{Fig: xxx}
\end{figure}    

















\section{RESULTS}
\subsection{GENERAL ANALYSIS}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.png}
    \caption{ }
    \label{Fig: xxx}
\end{figure}    

 
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}
    \caption{It is }
    \label{Fig: xxx}
\end{figure}     

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{5.png}
    \caption{It is }
    \label{Fig: xxx}
\end{figure}    

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{6.png}
    \caption{It is }
    \label{Fig: xxx}
\end{figure}    

\subsection{RQ1}
\begin{figure*}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{7}
    \caption{}
    \label{Fig: xxx}
\end{figure*}   


\subsection{RQ2}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{8}
    \caption{ }
    \label{Fig: xxx}
\end{figure}    


\subsection{Discussion}


\section{Threats to Validity}
\section{Related Works}
\section{Conclusion}








\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{final_paper_bibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that the ToC being cut off? Or is it actual sections within your document? We would need something to replicate the results, not just a code snippet as you've presented here. Can you update your question with code that includes something that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile to replicate the issue?

Comment: I have added an extra image to give you more details.

Comment: @werner Please look at my updated code.

Comment: Okay, it's clear from the image and your code that you've created a blank(-ish) template with a number of sectional units. These sectional units don't contain any text between them and since TeX naturally makes sectional units stick to the paragraph that follows them, they stick to each other instead... causing the overflow. Once you have your document filled with text, the flow should happen without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I only made some tidy up to your MWE  and included dummy text and figures  in the proper places. As recommended by IEEEtrans  I added `flushend`   to balance the columns of the last page and used `[ht]` instead of `[h]`. It compiled OK without warnings.

If you are still experiencing difficulties with your document it is not coming from this setup.

[image: a]

[image: c]

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[compsoc,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text added

\usepackage{flushend} %balance columns last page added

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{xxx\\
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} xxx} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department of yyy} \\
\textit{zzz}\\
\\
}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\kant[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
component, formatting, style, styling, insert
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
\kant[2-3]
\section{Background}
\kant[5-6]
\section{Study Design}
\kant[7-8] 
\subsection{ Research Question}
In this section, stemming from the above background reasoning for the research problems, we formulate the following research questions? \\
RQ1 : What are the xxx?\\
RQ2 : What are the xxx?

\kant[1]
\subsection{Method}
\kant[9]
\subsubsection{SLR}
\kant[10]

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{5cm}|}
\hline   
    & i1: xxx  \\
    & i2: xxx   \\
xxx     & i3: xxx   \\
    & i4: xxx   \\
    & i5: xxx  \\
    
\hline
    & R1: xxx  \\
   & R2: xxx   \\
   & R3: xxx   \\
xxx    & R4: xxx   \\
   & R5: xxx   \\
   & R6: xxx   \\
   & R7: xxx   \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{ }
    \label{Fig: xxx1}
\end{figure}  

\subsubsection{Grey Literature}
\kant[11-13]

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{grey literature type}
    \label{Fig: xxx2}
\end{figure}    

\section{RESULTS}
\kant[14-15]
\subsection{GENERAL ANALYSIS}
\kant[17]
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{ }
    \label{Fig: xxx3}
\end{figure}    
 
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{It is }
    \label{Fig: xxx4}
\end{figure}     

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{It is }
    \label{Fig: xxx5}
\end{figure}    

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{It is }
    \label{Fig: xxx6}
\end{figure}    

\subsection{RQ1}
\kant[18]
\begin{figure*}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
    \label{Fig: xxx7}
\end{figure*}  

\subsection{RQ2}
\kant[19]
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{ }
    \label{Fig: xxx8}
\end{figure}  
\subsection{Discussion}
\kant[20-22]
\section{Threats to Validity}
\kant[20-22]
\section{Related Works}
\kant[22-24]
\section{Conclusion}
\kant[26-29]

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{final_paper_bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi simon thanks for your answer however I still face the issue. But I will fill up my document and see if it's still an issue.